# orderby comment_count not working

Tags: sidebar, wordpress

I'm trying to display the 5 most commented posts of the past week in a Wordpress sidebar. Simplified I'm using this code:

```
<ul class="popular_posts">
<?php
wp_reset_postdata();
$pc = new WP_Query('orderby=comment_count&order=DESC&posts_per_page=5');

while ($pc->have_posts()) : $pc->the_post(); ?>
<li>
<strong><?php comments_popup_link('', '1', '%'); ?></strong>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
```

It works on every page apart from the home page where it just shows them in a random order. It's as if it ignores the orderby part.

I've tried:

- putting wp_reset_postdata() before/after the query
- using posts_orderby instead of orderby
- preceding the code with `remove_all_filters('posts_orderby')`

Has anyone got any idea what I'm missing? I've spent the past 2 day trying to figure this out with no joy.

Thanks!

Comment: There are too many possibilities based on the information provided. My guess would be that the query on the homepage is being modified.

Turn off all your plugins to make sure it's theme based.

Then go through your theme code to find something that could be causing it. My guess would be the query is being modified using `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: can you plz tell me that which page is your home page means you use template or index.php for home. you need to set static front page as a home page so plz go Settings > Reading > Front page and set your home page and after that you need to add that code and it work. Thanks

Comment: Add `suppress_filters=true` to your arguments. If it works, you have bad instance of `pre_get_posts` somewhere

Comment: It turns out another plugin was modifying the query - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a solution for your issue!

```
$most_comment_posts_args  = array(

'orderby' => 'comment_count',
'posts_per_page' => 9);

$most_comment_posts= new WP_Query($most_comment_posts_args );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.