# How to get posts orderby comment_count ascending and where to place the code? (Wordpress REST API)

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

I am a complete beginner when it comes to extending Wordpress REST API. I need to extend the API so that a request to `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?orderby=comment_count&order=asc` would yield a response with posts that are ordered by comment count in ascending order ie. posts with the least amount of comments appear first.

I skimmed through the REST API Handbook and watched a couple of [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2twS9ArdCI), but found no answer to my problem. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50552641/5964318) and it looks promising, however I'm not entirely sure if the code provided there fits my needs. From what I could gather WP_Query class is what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to make use of it. My second problem is that I don't know where exactly to place any code I may have stumbled upon ie. which file is supposed to play host to the code eventually?

I would greatly appreciate detailed answers and possibly sources for more information regarding this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to WordPress documentation `orderby` only accept following parameters:
`author, date, id, include, modified, parent, relevance, slug, include_slugs, title`

But you can add custom parameters to `orderby` if you have access to Wordpress website code. Please follow the below URL:

https://www.timrosswebdevelopment.com/wordpress-rest-api-post-order/

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this looks promising. I do have access to the Wordpress website code, however I still don't know how to include this piece of code into the API? Can you help?

Comment: yes, I can help

Comment: I added the code you linked for me into `\wp-includes\functions.php` and it works great. Many thanks!